# Remove SwiftLint installed from package

Tags: macos, swiftlint

I installed SwiftLint from [official packages](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/releases/).
Now, I desire remove completely and install from Homebrew.
I did not find official documentation about uninstall SwiftLint.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Makefile](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Makefile), run

```
rm -rf "/Library/Frameworks/SwiftLintFramework.framework"
rm -f "/usr/local/bin/swiftlint"
```

Answer (score 10):

### Uninstall

```
brew unlink swiftlint
brew uninstall --force swiftlint
```

### Install

```
brew install swiftlint
```